# How do extract Big Query DAILY data into WEEKLY numbers, with Monday as the first day of the week?

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get aggregated data (from GA BigQuery) in a weekly format with Monday as the first day. However, when I use the the script below I get the following error:

Expected results:

```
PARTITION_WEEK  _DistClients
2023-05-15       1234   
2023-05-08       4321
```

Error message:

> No matching signature for function DATE_TRUNC for argument types: STRING, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signatures: DATE_TRUNC(DATE, DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_TRUNC(DATETIME, DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART, [STRING])

Script used:

```
INSERT INTO `table name` 

SELECT
DATE_TRUNC(Date, WEEK(MONDAY)) AS PARTITION_WEEK,
COUNT(DISTINCT(clientId)) as _DistClients,
  
FROM `table name`
GROUP BY PARTITION_WEEK
ORDER BY PARTITION_WEEK DESC
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Error says `Date` column is not a `DATE` type but a `STRING` type in your table. You need to cast or parse it to `DATE` type first and apply `DATE_TRUNC` function.

Comment: Thanks @Jaytiger...much appreciated. I've tried the following but doesn't work: 

PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",Date) AS PARTITION_WEEK,
DATE_TRUNC(Date, WEEK(MONDAY)) AS PARTITION_WEEK,
COUNT(DISTINCT(clientId)) as _DistClients,

Can you help with how I should write the script? Thanks

Comment: Would you try `DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",Date), WEEK(MONDAY)) AS PARTITION_WEEK` ?

Comment: Brilliant, that's resolved it. Thanks for your help @Jaytiger!

Comment: Hi @Jaytiger. Now that the weekly data is coming through as expected (thanks!), I’ve a similar problem for monthly numbers. This is the expected results:

Year_Mon     DistClients
2023-5       12345

I need to format the date to %y-%m. I’ve tried the following but doesn’t work. Do you have any suggestions?

SELECT
DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%y-%m',DATE), MONTH) AS Year_Mon,
COUNT(DISTINCT(clientId)) as _DistClients,
  
FROM `table name`
GROUP BY Year_Mon
ORDER BY Year_Mon DESC

After query completed I see the following error message: Failed to parse input string "20210214"

Comment: I've added answer for your follow-up question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the expected output,

```
PARTITION_WEEK  _DistClients
2023-05-15       1234   
2023-05-08       4321
```

You can consider below query.

```sql
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",Date), WEEK(MONDAY)) AS PARTITION_WEEK,
       COUNT(DISTINCT clientId) AS _DistClients,
  FROM `table name`
 GROUP BY 1;
```

And for the monthly aggregation,

```
Year_Mon DistClients
2023-5   12345
```

```sql
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", Date)) AS Year_Mon,
       COUNT(DISTINCT clientId) AS _DistClients,
  FROM `table name`
 GROUP BY 1;
```